# Show/hide text area box + swap between image onclick

Tags: javascript

I am creating form page where I wanted to hide text area box when clicked on image as well as to swap the image and vice-versa. Right now I am able to hide/show div but image is not displayed when text area box is hidden and also does not return to first image. There are 2 scripts one for div show/hide and another to swap image.

```
1. image: output before click
2. image: after hitting on an image



    <script>
     function showhide(id){ 
      if (document.getElementById){ 
       obj = document.getElementById(id); 
       if (obj.style.display == "none"){ 
        obj.style.display = ""; 
       } else { 
        obj.style.display = "none"; 
       } 
      } 
     } 
    var onImg= "testim.png, valm.png";
    var offImg= "testip.png, valp.png";
    </script>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    <ul id="text_type_tab" name="text_type_tab">
        <li id="PR_TEXT_TAB" class="tab_active"> <a href="javascript:showhide('textInputField1');"><img src="testim.png" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImg : offImg);" align="middle"/></li></a>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <table id="hidden_content" width="80%" align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="textInputField1" name="textInputField1" style="resize:vertical; width: 900px;" rows="15" cols="105" wrap="pre" onblur="onTextSubmitFunction('Apply')"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>





Please help.
Thanks a lot, in advance!



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PwdK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j6FE.png
```

Comment: I only see the function to change the display of an id, I don't see any other javascript (like one to listen to a click event). Do you have any other code?

Comment: @fauxserious the image inside the anchor has some code on the onClick handler too. :) I guess that never gets called.

Comment: this variable "testim.png, valm.png"; shouldn't it represent the href link to one image? and swap this image with a single image..kindly clarify....

Comment: Also the parameter you pass to "javascript:showhide('textInputField1)" is hidding the text area box not a div...kindly shed some light on this....

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying                                                               @repzero: Actually, I want to hide the text area box only which is working now. But when I click on image text area is hidden but image is not displayed. I can show/hide box but not able to swap between image. I am attaching the images of desired result before and after the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pointer 1**

Change the below variable to the absolute link of your image

```
var onImg= "testim.png, valm.png"; //this should be one link
var offImg= "testip.png, valp.png"; //this should be one link
```

(Just to be on the safe side for testing test)

example

```
 var onImg= "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHrNNGyEGlgXtd5u4fq1eQ18z8TMXHCZqf_4zI9yz6uo7N8KeXuFVRr-tR";
 var offImg= "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8x25Dihzxt-pilDC6-SAVJ8JEVB4VItyjJhRFFuAGNFPx5YBbR5rQST01";
```

---

**Pointer 2**

change

```
 <li id="PR_TEXT_TAB" class="tab_active"> <a href="javascript:showhide('textInputField1');"><img src="testim.png" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImg : offImg);" align="middle"/></li></a>
    </ul>
```

to this

```
 <li id="PR_TEXT_TAB" class="tab_active"> <a href="javascript:showhide('textInputField1');"><img src="testim.png" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImg : offImg);" align="middle"/></a></li>
    </ul>
```

that is it should be `</a></li>` instead of `</li></a>`

---

**Pointer 3**

Change this

`<a href="javascript:showhide('textInputField1');">`

to this

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showhide('textInputField1')">
```

Attach it directly to the onclick event since href attribute simply points to a location.

here is a snippet

```html
-    <script>
     function showhide(id){ 
      if (document.getElementById){ 
       obj = document.getElementById(id); 
          obj.style.display == "none"?obj.style.display = "":obj.style.display = "none"; 
          
      // if (obj.style.display == "none"){ 
      //  obj.style.display = "":; 
      // } 
          //else { 
       // obj.style.display = "none"; 
       //} 
      } 
     } 
    var onImg= "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHrNNGyEGlgXtd5u4fq1eQ18z8TMXHCZqf_4zI9yz6uo7N8KeXuFVRr-tR";
    var offImg= "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8x25Dihzxt-pilDC6-SAVJ8JEVB4VItyjJhRFFuAGNFPx5YBbR5rQST01";
    </script>


    <div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    <ul id="text_type_tab" name="text_type_tab">
        <li id="PR_TEXT_TAB" class="tab_active"> <a href="#" onclick="javascript:showhide('textInputField1')"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8x25Dihzxt-pilDC6-SAVJ8JEVB4VItyjJhRFFuAGNFPx5YBbR5rQST01" onclick="this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImg : offImg);" align="middle"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <table id="hidden_content" width="80%" align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="textInputField1" name="textInputField1" style="resize:vertical; width: 900px;" rows="15" cols="105" wrap="pre" onblur="onTextSubmitFunction('Apply')"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Images are getting swapped in Chrome & Mozilla but  in IE11, only first image is displayed all the time. All settings are OK for IE like scripting "Enable". Any guess?